# Python txt files, average, information

Tags: python, file, text, average

i have a .txt file with this(it should be random names, tho):

```
My Name 4 8 7 
Your Name 5 8 7 
You U 5 9 7
My My 4 8 5
Y Y 8 7 9
```

I need to put the information into text file results.txt with the names + average of the numbers. How do I do that?

```
with open(r'stuff.txt') as f:
    mylist = list(f)

i = 0
sk = len(mylist)
while i < sk - 4:
    print(mylist[i], mylist[i+1], mylist[i+2], mylist[i+3])
    i = i + 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, open both the input and output files:

```
with open("stuff.txt") as in_file:
    with open("results.txt", "w") as out_file:
```

Since the problem only needs to work on each line independently, a simple loop over each `line` would suffice:

```
        for line in in_file:
```

Split each line at the whitespaces into list of strings (`row`):

```
            row = line.split()
```

The numbers occur after the first two fields:

```
            str_nums = row[2:]
```

However, these are still strings, so they must be converted to a floating-point number to allow arithmetic to be performed on them.  This results in a list of floats (`nums`):

```
            nums = map(float, str_nums)
```

Now calculate the average:

```
            avg = sum(nums) / len(str_nums)
```

Finally, write the names and the average into the output file.

```
            out_file.write("{} {} {}\n".format(row[0], row[1], avg))
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
with open(fname) as f:
   new_lines = []
   lines = f.readlines()       
   for each in lines:          
     col = each.split()
     l = len(col)#<-- length of each line
     average = (int(col[l-1])+int(col[l-2])+int(col[l-3]))/3
     new_lines.append(col[0]+col[1]+str(average) + '\n')
   for each in new_lines:#rewriting new lines into file 
     f.write(each)
   f.close()
```

Comment: Why can't average be `average = (int(col[2])+int(col[3])+int(col[4]))/3`? Why do we need the length of a line? Honest question, I'm learning Python.

Comment: @AndyG, i am coming from backwards since all 3 numbers are the last 3 item in the line. i am making sure that i am really taking 3 numbers. if the line becomes suddenly ``A B C D 12 23 3``, then ``col[3]`` will be a string.. does this make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. Wouldn't you want `len(col)` instead of `len(each)` in that case?

Comment: nope, col is each item in the line. i need the line length and from that, i will infer to last 3 items of line.. what do you think

Comment: But `len(each)` returns the length of the entire string (not the number of columns), which could be more than the number of indices in the columns, so `col[l-1]` would be out of range. I tested this code with OP's example. On a side note, you probably want spaces between the strings you append in `new_lines`

Comment: @AndyG, oh you are right.. sorry, i thought more in awk-way. thanks dude

Comment: :-) Thank you for admitting that. I panicked a bit because I thought I was misunderstanding things I'm learning.

Comment: @AndyG no dude, i am also learning python.. you are good dont worry.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried, and this worked:

```
inputtxt=open("stuff.txt", "r")
outputtxt=open("output.txt", "w")
output=""""""
for i in inputtxt.readlines():
    nums=[]
    name=""
    for k in i:
        try:
            nums.append(int(k))
        except:
            if k!=" ":
                name+=k
    avrg=0
    for j in nums:
        avrg+=j
    avrg/=len(nums)
    line=name+" "+str(avrg)+"\n"
    output+=line
outputtxt.write(output)
inputtxt.close()
outputtxt.close()
```

Comment: It did, however, remove spaces in names